# CSV row appending: DictWriter always writes from first column

Tags: python, csv

**Input file:**

```
$ cat test.csv 
company,spread,cat1,cat2,cat3
A,XYZ,32,67,0
B,XYZ,43,0,432
C,XYZ,32,76,32
D,XYZ,454,87,43
E,XYZ,0,0,65
F,XYZ,0,0,7
```

**Expected CSV output** (Sum columns `cat1`, `cat2` and `cat3` and append the sum.):

```
$ cat test.csv 
company,spread,cat1,cat2,cat3
A,XYZ,32,67,0
B,XYZ,43,0,432
C,XYZ,32,76,32
D,XYZ,454,87,43
E,XYZ,0,0,65
F,XYZ,0,0,7
,,561,230,579
```

**Code:**

```
import csv

all_keys = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
default_values = {i: 0 for i in all_keys}

def read_csv():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        yield from reader

for row in read_csv():
    for i in all_keys:
        default_values[i] += int(row[i])

with open('test.csv', 'a') as w:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=all_keys)
    writer.writerow(default_values)
```

**Actual Output:**

```
$ cat test.csv 
company,spread,cat1,cat2,cat3
A,XYZ,32,67,0
B,XYZ,43,0,432
C,XYZ,32,76,32
D,XYZ,454,87,43
E,XYZ,0,0,65
F,XYZ,0,0,7
561,230,579
```

**Question:**

The `csv.DictWriter` is not appending row with correct column alignment. I understand that I have 5 columns but I am providing values for only 3 columns. But I thought as this is `DictWriter`, it will append values to only a matching column header. If I open my `Actual Output` CSV, it is quite visual that columns are not aligned:

[image]

Comment: The optional restval parameter specifies the value to be written if the dictionary is missing a key in fieldnames. From here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. So DictWriter(f, fieldnames, restval=”....) should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the column names for the first two in `fieldnames`:

```
with open('test.csv', 'a') as w:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=['company', 'spread']+all_keys)
    writer.writerow(default_values)
```

Blank values will be written to the first two columns if the keys are not available in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare you writter like that:

```
with open('test.csv', 'a') as w:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=all_keys, restval=' ')
    writer.writerow(default_values)
```

So you don't have to specify all the missing keys : for all the missing keys, restval char will fill with the value you chose. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Comment: I tried that. But it isn't working. Same result as before. Is something wrong in my code? It as good as `restval` parameter is completely ignored.

Comment: I have accepted the @moses answer. However, I am interested to know why the `restval` not working for me. +1 for your time.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer `restval` only works for keys existing in the `fieldnames`. In fact my solution uses `restval` also, whose default value is `''`; I don't need to explicitly pass it.