# How to append row to dictwriter python

Tags: python

I have the following code to create and write the csvfile.

```
with open("A:\\example_results\\testing.csv", "w") as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name'], dialect="excel", delimiter=";")
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
            writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
            writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

Later if I want to open the file and append rows into it, how do I get the dictwriter and do the job. Now I am doing like this,

```
with open("A:\\example_results\\testing.csv", "a") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name'], dialect="excel", delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'asdasdasd', 'last_name': 'asdasd'})
```

But why should I specify all the parameters again inside DictWriter ? Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: Open the file in append mode and create a new dictwriter to do the job?

Comment: But why should I give fieldnames again on Dictwriter while appending. Is there a cleaner code to do this

Comment: If you want to reuse the same dictwriter, you have to save it somewhere and you must keep the file open.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118681/csv-row-appending-dictwriter-always-writes-from-first-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import csv   
with open(r'A:\\example_results\\testing.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter =';')
    writer.writerow(['111111', '222222222222'])
```

Comment: Does not work because the delimiters and header alignment, dialect is gone.

Comment: Updated the delimiter param

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just use the append parameter. If you create your file right before, and know you would have nothing in it, it is just more convenient and clearer this way.

I would do.

```
with open('foo.txt', 'a') as file:
    for _ in xrange(0, 10):
        file.write('Hello World !~\n')
```

There wouldn't need to have your filePath twice. However, if you **really** want to keep it this way, I believe you should just do...

```
filePath = 'foo.txt'
# 'write' parameter
with open(filePath, 'w') as file:
    for _ in xrange(0, 10):
        file.write('Hello World !~\n')

# 'append' parameter
with open(filePath, 'a') as file:
    for _ in xrange(0, 10):
        file.write('Hello World !~\n')
```